# Validar URL escondida em tabelas html com C#

Tags: c#

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um bot para captura de determinadas informações dentro do site de tribunal de contas de um Estado, porém conforme a validação das páginas que é feita por ano me deparei com a seguinte situação:

-algumas páginas possuí um link escondido que redireciona para um popup mais detalhado e outras não, sendo assim 1 página com link e 1 página sem link, para isso eu preciso capturar ambas as informações, tantos as desse link quanto as de modo geral.

Existe alguma condição de do while ou if em que eu possa validar a existência deste link? o trecho do código que valida o link é este:

```
Response itens1 = bot.Get("http://portaldocidadao.tce.sc.gov.br/" + html2.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='de1']/tr[@class='sr']").Attributes["onclick"].Value.CopyBetween("location.href='", "'").Trim());
var html3 = itens1.Html();
Item itens = new Item();
itens.quantidade = html3.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='sr']/td")[3].SelectSingleNode("div").InnerText.ToDecimal();
itens.quantidade = html3.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='dr']/td")[3].SelectSingleNode("div").InnerText.ToDecimal();
/*validar valores unitários */
itens.valor_unitario = html3.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='sr']/td")[5].SelectSingleNode("div").InnerText.Trim().ToDecimal();
itens.valor_total = html3.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='sr']/td")[5].SelectSingleNode("div").InnerText.Trim().ToDecimal();
itens.descricao = html3.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='sr']/td")[1].SelectSingleNode("div").InnerText.Trim();
Documento.itens.Add(itens);
```

Comment: apresente o html de exemplo